# Why is $x\log(x)$ convex?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, logarithms

> Why is $x\log(x)$ convex?

According to the definition it must hold:

$(tx+(1-t)y)\log(tx+(1-t)y)\le tx\log(x)+(1-t)y\log(y)$

for all positive $x,y$ and $t\in[0,1]$

edit: It is allowed to derive, but i have to prove using the definition.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since $f(x)=x \log x$ is $C^2$, you can derive twice, and see that 
$$f''(x)=\frac{1}{x}>0. $$

Comment: Hello @user1337 , what is C^2?

Comment: @QuestionEverything The class of continuously twice-differentiable functions.

Answer (score 11):

Given your name, you should know that a function is convex if its second derivative is positive...

Comment: ahah ok. is there no other proofs without derivating, i mean using the definition ?

Comment: Yes, there are, but they are much more complicated...