# Quantum relative entropy and convexity of some function

Tags: convex-analysis, information-theory, quantum-mechanics, entropy, quantum-information

Let $d_0$, $d_1$, $\rho$ positive matrices of $M_n$ of trace one. We consider the state
$$
d_t=(1-t)d_0+td_1
$$
for any $0 \le t \le 1$. We suppose that the relative entropy $S(d_t|\rho)$ is finite for any $t \in [0,1]$. Consider the function $$f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^+,\, t \mapsto S(d_t|\rho)=\mathrm{tr}( d_t \log d_t -d_t\log \rho).$$

I read in the book "Quantum information theory..." p.97 of Petz that $f$ is convex. I does not understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for any $0<\lambda<1$

$$\begin{eqnarray} d_{\lambda t_1 + (1-\lambda) t_2} & = & (1-\lambda t_1 - (1-\lambda) t_2)d_0+(\lambda t_1 + (1-\lambda) t_2)d_1 \\
& = & (1-\lambda + \lambda - \lambda t_1 - (1-\lambda) t_2)d_0 + (\lambda t_1 + (1-\lambda) t_2)d_1 \\
& = & (\lambda (1 - t_1) + (1-\lambda) (1- t_2))d_0 + (\lambda t_1 + (1-\lambda) t_2)d_1 \\
& = & \lambda ((1 - t_1) d_0 + t_1 d_1) + (1-\lambda) ((1- t_2)d_0 + t_2d_1) \\
& = & \lambda d_{t_1} + (1-\lambda) d_{t_2} \; .\end{eqnarray}$$

Combined with the convexity of the function $x\log x$, this suffices to show that $f$ is convex as well.

Comment: I understand the first computation (I observed this). My problem is your last sentence.

Comment: The function $f$ has as the essential building block $x\log x$ (the first term in the trace). The other term is just linear so trivially convex. $x\log x$ is also a convex function. There's the added complexity that you're evaluating in operators, but since you're taking the trace, the end result is a number anyway.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/594300/why-is-x-logx-convex